# Confluence stopped working with 404

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, confluence

### Problem

Atlassian confluence 3.4.9 standalone (on Windows 7 64 bit with Oracle 11GR2) stopped working with 404 response.

If I looked at the Tomcat and Confluence logs, it looks there is no JDBC Datasource to talk to, however the database is up and running and no configuration has been changed.

The Oracle instance NR is up and running and the database can be connected. 
No OS/Network change has been made. It was working last time I started on 13MAY2015.

Kindly suggest where to look at and how to debug.

[image: 404]

## catalina log

```
May 19, 2015 11:10:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
May 19, 2015 11:10:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
May 19, 2015 11:10:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
May 19, 2015 11:10:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
May 19, 2015 11:10:05 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 19, 2015 11:10:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 305 ms
May 19, 2015 11:10:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Tomcat-Standalone
May 19, 2015 11:10:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
May 19, 2015 11:10:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 19, 2015 11:10:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
May 19, 2015 11:10:20 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 19, 2015 11:10:20 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 19, 2015 11:10:20 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6b950106]) and a value of type [org.dom4j.DocumentFactory] (value [org.dom4j.DocumentFactory@3766818]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 19, 2015 11:10:20 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.atlassian.core.logging.ThreadLocalErrorCollection$2] (value [com.atlassian.core.logging.ThreadLocalErrorCollection$2@6914225f]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 19, 2015 11:10:22 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 19, 2015 11:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 16464 ms
May 19, 2015 11:35:22 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 19, 2015 11:35:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Tomcat-Standalone
May 19, 2015 11:35:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Standalone].[localhost].[/] has not been started
May 19, 2015 11:35:23 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

## atlassian-confluence.log

```
2015-05-19 11:10:09,652 INFO [main] [com.atlassian.confluence.lifecycle] contextInitialized Starting Confluence 3.4.9 (build #2042)
2015-05-19 11:10:13,536 INFO [main] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] init Initialising the plugin system
2015-05-19 11:10:13,951 INFO [main] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] init Plugin system started in 0:00:00.412
2015-05-19 11:10:16,160 WARN [main] [atlassian.config.xml.AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister] saveDocumentAtomically Unable to move D:\Home\Self\Repositories\Confluence\confluence.cfg.xml2349617058309685196tmp to D:\Home\Self\Repositories\Confluence\confluence.cfg.xml. Falling back to non-atomic overwrite.
2015-05-19 11:10:16,176 INFO [main] [springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2015-05-19 11:10:18,832 INFO [main] [com.atlassian.confluence.lifecycle] <init> Loading EhCache cache manager
2015-05-19 11:10:20,269 FATAL [main] [sf.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider] configure Could not find datasource: java:comp/env/jdbc/confluence
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at net.sf.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:44)
    at net.sf.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:83)
    at net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:76)
    at net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1187)
    at net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:818)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:540)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:718)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:718)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:820)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at com.atlassian.spring.container.ContainerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContainerContextLoaderListener.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

## server.xml

```
<Server port="8000" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="0">
    <Service name="Tomcat-Standalone">
        <Connector className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector" port="8080" minProcessors="5"
                   maxProcessors="75"
                   enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="10" debug="0" connectionTimeout="20000"
                   useURIValidationHack="false" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

        <Engine name="Standalone" defaultHost="localhost" debug="0">

            <Host name="localhost" debug="0" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">

                <Context path="" docBase="../confluence" debug="0" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                    <!-- Logger is deprecated in Tomcat 5.5. Logging configuration for Confluence is specified in confluence/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties -->
                    <!-- Oracle Configuration -->
                    <Resource
                         name="jdbc/confluence"
                         auth="Container"
                         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                         url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/NR"
                         username="confluence"
                         password=*****
                         connectionProperties="SetBigStringTryClob=true"
                         maxActive="25"
                         maxIdle="5"
                         maxWait="10000"
                     />
                    <Manager pathname="" />
                </Context>
            </Host>

        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the database account expired on 15MAY2015.